# Image upload: Unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, image, upload, syntax-error

I have the following code:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['uid']['name'];  
$user= 'FILENAME';   
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
$new_file_name=$user . '.' . $ext;   
$path= "uploads/images/users/".$new_file_name;    
$upload = $_FILES['uid']  
$info = getimagesize( $upload['tmp_name'] );  
if ( $info[2] != IMAGETYPE_JPEG )  
{  
echo "File format is not supported!";  
}  
if ( filesize( $upload[ 'tmp_name' ] ) > 3485760 )  
{  
echo "The filesize is too large!";  
}  
else(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uid']['tmp_name'], $path))  
{  
echo "Successful<BR/>";  
echo "File Name :".$new_file_name."<BR/>";  
echo "File Size :".$_FILES['uid']['size']."<BR/>";   
echo "File Type :".$_FILES['uid']['type']."<BR/>";  
}
```

I am failing to see what the problem is.
The error occurs on line 8, which starts with `$path`.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: post the error message if you can.

Comment: **Don't remove the information from your question.** To mark your question as answered, click the tick outline next to the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a semicolon at:

`$upload = $_FILES['uid']`

You will need to change it to:

`$upload = $_FILES['uid'];`

And like Capsule said, you will need to change the `else` statement to something like this:

```
elseif(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uid']['tmp_name'], $path))
{
echo "Successful
";
```

Comment: DOH! id been looking for something simple!

Comment: now it is saying unexpected { on line 18 (above the successful echo)..

Comment: See my answer. else will never be followed by a parenthesis...

Comment: I see, have a look at Capsule's answer.

Comment: @Capsule: We posted our comments at the same time lol.

Comment: `else if` not just else.  u have a conditional there

Comment: even after making the suggested changes it isnt working how it should unfortunately..it should only allow jpegs to be uploaded - it currently gives the message filetype not supported + successful for a png and the png does get uploaded...any help on this one?

Comment: @Bob because you didn't specify it. should really read up on a basic tutorial about file upload in php. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php

Comment: @Michiel make a wish ;-)

Comment: @kjy112 I'd even recommend to read a tutorial about PHP ;-)

Comment: All much appreciated - got it working now

Comment: i didnt see the point in starting a new question on the same subject.

Comment: @Bob: No problem, glad you have fixed it!

Comment: @Bob because other people might be interested? Your initial question is about a basic php error, not file type handling.

Answer (score 3):

```
else(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uid']['tmp_name'], $path))
```

?????????????????????

Comment: +1 For fixing the second problem!